# Intersystems Caché - Class for Data Encryption

Tags: encryption, caching, intersystems-cache

I wonder which class is the class that I use to encrypt data (first time string data) and the best method of encryption (among those supported by caché). Must generate a strong encryption for data in my project.

Any help is welcome.
If someone can show me some example, I'll be even more grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please state what exactly do you want to encrypt. To encrypt the whole database, there is a setting in System Management Portal, this encryption is certified in US. To encrypt data transfers, you may use SSH (see %Net.SSH.*), HTTPS (see %Net.HttpRequest with Https property), and Web Services with WS-Security (see documentation). To encrypt just any string internally, see $system.Encryption.Help().

Comment: Friend, you told me everything I wanted. In my case is to encrypt data string. But I must confess that part of SSH security caught my attention as well. Have you ever used? Greatly affect the performace of the database? @user364113

Answer (score 0):

We use ensemble web services to serve up Base64 encrypted XML payloads to web portals and mobile apps in the healthcare field.  The code we've implemented looks something like the below snippet, in addition to some other security features related to the web service.

```
Set sc = ..xmlData.XMLExportToString(.xml)
Set xmlReturn = ##class(%System.Encryption).Base64Encode(xml)
Quit xmlReturn
```